# Schedule at 24hrs interval

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to know the best method to schedule a code. I have a code that generates reports and sends mail to a set of people at interval of 24hrs. Its a console based java application. I want to know the best method to schedule that. Sometimes I may need to change that to 12hrs interval. However the application doesn't perform any other task in between the interval.

Comment: should be system independent. might be linux or windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are few approach, from simplest to most comprehensive:

1. `sleep()`:

   ```
   TimeUnit.HOURS.sleep(24)
   ```

   This approach is very simple, do the work and sleep for 24 hours. Actually it is a bit more complex because the report generation takes some time, so you have to sleep slightly shorter. All solutions below handle this transparently.
2. [`java.util.Timer#scheduleAtFixedRate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) - simple, built-in Java solution.
3. `@Scheduled` annotation in [spring](/questions/tagged/spring) or `@Schedule` in [ejb](/questions/tagged/ejb) - more complex but also more powerful, e.g. accepts [cron](/questions/tagged/cron) expressions:

   ```
   @Scheduled(fixedRate=DateUtils.MILLIS_PER_DAY)
   public void generateReport() {
     //...
   }
   ```
4. [quartz-scheduler](/questions/tagged/quartz-scheduler) - full blown Java scheduler with clustering and fail-over, misfire handling, full [cron](/questions/tagged/cron) support, etc. Very comprehensive:

   ```
   newTrigger().
     withSchedule(
       simpleSchedule().
         withIntervalInHours(24).
         repeatForever()
       ).build();
   ```

   or

   ```
   newTrigger().
     withSchedule(
       cronSchedule().
         dailyAtHourAndMinute(17, 30).  //17:30
       ).build();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I am using two ways:

First for non managed code like client code:
[Chron4J](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/cron4j/)

Second is implmented in the JavaEE framewoks. You can use it via annotating methods when you use an container like Glassfish/JBoss. Would be something like this:

```
@Schedule(second="*/1", minute="*",hour="*", persistent=false)
public void doWork(){
    System.out.println("timer: " + helloService.sayHello());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the quartz scheduler if I were you.
I used in a number of applications and it's really easy to use.
You can find more information here: http://quartz-scheduler.org/

If you use the spring stack I would surely recommend it, since it is super easy to configure in xml and let spring inject all the stuff for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the program can be idle try something like this

```
try
{
for (;;) {
    //code
    Thread.sleep(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    //code
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
     System.out.println(e);
}
```